# Segmentation fault when using fgets with array of strings

Tags: c, file

I need to add a line of a file to a array of strings but am getting a segmentation fault when it hits the fgets function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 
    char **array = malloc((sizeof(char) * 100) * 3);
    fgets(*(array), 100, file);
    printf("%s\n", *array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I am trying to add the first line of the file ("My name is bob" is the first line) and set it to the zeroth element of the array. I am getting a segmentation whenever it hits the fgets statement.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: You're allocating an array of characters, then interpreting that as **an array of pointers**. Dumping data into a random pointer → undefined behaviour → probable crash. If you want to treat this as a buffer like that, you'll need to write to `&array[0]`, `&array[100]`, etc.

Comment: Why even bother dynamically allocating the array?

Comment: You are wasting time if you don't check return values.

Comment: @Jman4546, Note that with `char **array`, `array` is **not** an array of _strings_, but a pointer, a pointer (of type `char **`) to a pointer (of type `char *`).  Pointers are not arrays.  Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: If we answered your question below please accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.  That way we know you are all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting a segmentation whenever it hits the fgets statement.

After

```
char **array = malloc((sizeof(char) * 100) * 3);
```

`array` points to to the *uninitialized* allocated memory.

With:

```
fgets(*(array), 100, file);
```

`*array` is *bad* as the memory `array` points to is *initialized*.  Code is passing a pointer, with an indeterminant value resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

To form an *array* (size 3) of strings (using a size 100 char array) with 1 allocation:

```
#define ARRAY_N 3 
#define STRING_SZ 100 
char (*array_alt)[STRING_SZ] = malloc(sizeof *array_alt * ARRAY_N);
if (array_alt) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_N; i++) {
    if (fgets(array_alt[i], sizeof array_alt[i], file) == NULL) {
      array_alt[i][0] = '\0';
    }
    printf("<%s>\n", array_alt[i]);
  }
  free(array_alt);
}
```

With `char (*array_alt)[STRING_SZ]`, `array` is a [pointer to array 100 of `char`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*array_alt%29%5B100%5D).

Here `array_alt[i]` refences an *array* of `char`, size 100.  Giving that to `fgets()`, it is converted to the type (a `char *`) and address of its first element (`&array_alt[i][0])`, just what `fgets()` expects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the return value from `fopen()`.
2. Check the return value from `malloc()`.
3. `char **array = malloc((sizeof(char) * 100) * 3);` allocates 300 bytes which you say are `char *` then try to write `char` in it.  Dereferencing uninitialized data is undefined behavior.
4. Close your file handle with `fclose(file)` is a good practice.
5. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values.

If you want to do it dynamically you could use a pointer to array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_LEN 100
#define LINES 3

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!file) {
        perror("test.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    char (*array)[LINES][LINE_LEN] = malloc(sizeof *array);
    if(!array) {
        perror("malloc");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    fgets(*array[0], sizeof *array[0], file);
    printf("%s\n", *array[0]);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

or an array of string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_LEN 100
#define LINES 3

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!file) {
        perror("test.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    char (*array)[LINE_LEN] = malloc(sizeof *array * LINES);
    if(!array) {
        perror("malloc");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    fgets(array[0], sizeof array[0], file);
    printf("%s\n", array[0]);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

It would be easier to use a stack allocated variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 100

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!file) {
        perror("test.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    char array[ARRAY_LEN];
    fgets(array, sizeof array, file);
    printf("%s\n", array);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```